# Prolog divisors

Tags: prolog

Write a predicate that calculates every divisors of every item in a list. (the divisor can't be 1 and himself).
That's how I did the code for divisors of a number. But I don't know more.

```
divides(N,D) :-
    0 is N mod D,
    D < N/2,
    D > 1.

divisors_0( N, D, R0,[D|R0] ) :-    divides(N,D).
divisors_0( N, D, R0,   R0  ) :- \+ divides(N,D).

divisors( _, 0,  R,  R ).
divisors( N, D0, R0, R ) :-
    divisors_0(N,D0,R0,R1),
    D is D0 - 1,
    divisors(N,D,R1,R).

divisors(X,R) :-
    X > 1,
    divisors(X,X,[],R),
    !.
```

For appelating I use : divisors(number *like 45,24, etc *, X)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

```
divisor(N1,N,[]):-
    N1 > N/2, !.
divisor(N1,N,[N1|T]):-
    N1 =< N/2,
    0 is N mod N1, !,
    N2 is N1 + 1,
    divisor(N2,N,T).
divisor(N1,N,L):-
    N1 =< N/2,
    N2 is N1 + 1,
    divisor(N2,N,L).
divisors(L,LR):-
    maplist(divisor(2),L,LR).

?- L = [11,12], divisors(L,LR).
L = [11, 12],
LR = [[], [2, 3, 4, 6]]
```